# Centering Rows of Image Buttons Within an HTML Form

Tags: html, css

**Background:** I have an **HTML form rendered from a template** in flask which **consists of 5 rows of buttons**, all of which are **images**. Each **`<div>`** automatically begins a new row of buttons, with each row aligned to left of the page.

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="/select" method="POST">
 <div>
  <input type=image/>
  <input type=image/>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type=image/>
  <input type=image/>
  <input type=image/>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Note:** I'm trying to **horizontally center each row** (rows vary in the number of buttons) with the CSS code below:

**CSS Code:**

```
input {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

div {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However, telling the CSS to center each row in this way is not working (each row starts on the left side), nor has applying `margin: 0 auto;` to `input` or any CSS selector I've tried creating. Is there a hidden complication from the form or flask rendering the template? Or am I just missing the proper place to define the margin property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set text-align: center in the div to horizontally center elements:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This resolved the issue. So then this is the proper replacement for `margin: auto`because images/buttons on the page are inline elements, right?

Comment: @J.ThomasShorty Yes, `text-align` works because the buttons are inline elements. `margin: auto` fails here because it also requires the width to be explicitly specified on the div.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this

```
<input type="image" src="submit.gif" align="right"  width="48" height="48">
```

You can set image to center aligned by sing align tag in your input element.